# DSL Modem Power circuit failure - LEDs are blinking incessantly without powering on

Tags: power-supply

I have a DLink DSL modem at home which started causing trouble recently. The device won't completely power on, but the LEDs blink in short strobe like manner. I thought it was a power switch problem and tried to short the power supply. But, then the problem reappeared intermittently. When testing the circuit, I tried shorting the switch using a digital multimeter in current measurement mode. The modem powered up consistently when shorted using the multimeter in this mode, but not when shorted using a wire or jumper.

What could be causing this behaviour? Could it be because of an AC filtering inductor that could have failed and the multimeter acting as an inductor in the current measurement mode?  Could you please also suggest a way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I guess you have just pushed some loose contacts with your multimeter.

Comment: That was my first thought too :) . But, I tried touching the multimeter terminals lightly enough to just close the circuit and still it worked. Also, I tried using a strong jumper wire and pressed against the contacts while shorting, but it did not turn the modem on, but the lights blinked in the problematic way.

Comment: The strobing effect suggests that the power supply is sensing an overload, shutting down and then retrying. The additional resistance of the multimeter in current mode might be just enough to keep the peak current below the trip threshold. What value of current does the multimeter show under these conditions, and how does it compare to the power supply rating?

Comment: I will check that tonight. But, what could be causing the overload, as the problem started suddenly and I could not see any resistor being damaged. But, I see couple of inductor coils. May be one of the coils is shorted. I will check that too. Thank you for your suggestion. I was not thinking in the direction of overload at all.

Comment: @Dave thank you for your suggestion. Isoldered on a 2.2 ohm resistor from an old conked circuit and it fixed the issue. I still could not identify what is causing the overload. But this is working for now. As a bonus I think the device will not heat up anymore, add it was happening in the last few days. Could you post your comment as answer, so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strobing effect suggests that the power supply is sensing an overload, shutting down and then retrying. The additional resistance of the multimeter in current mode might be just enough to keep the peak current below the trip threshold. What value of current does the multimeter show under these conditions, and how does it compare to the power supply rating?